# A server software that allows users to upload Python web applications

Tags: python, web-server

I teach a course in Python, where the students build web applications using Flask. I want to let the students upload their applications to the web.
Previously, I used the PythonAnywhere website, which has a free plan, but it is very limited - the applications go down after several months. I tried to use Heroku, but they have cancelled their free plans, and require each user to have a credit card before creating new applications.

My current plan is to rent a private server, and install on it a software that allows users to register and upload their Flask applications. It should be similar to the software used by PythonAnywhere or Heroku, but does not have to support many types of applications - only Flask-based applications. I can pay for the software, but it should be free for the students.

What software can I install on the server, so that my students can upload and run their Flask applications easily?